# Ports isn't setting up after getting node and links from DB

Tags: javascript, gojs

I'm selecting nodes and links from DB and pass it to GOJS by adding items to nodeDataArray and linkDataArray. Position works, but ports setting up automatically to the closest so I need to declare fromPort and toPort from DB too. I've tried just get from/to - Port by calling from console and its not setted and not available in array until I'd setted link to another port manually.

```
linkFromPortIdProperty: "fid",
linkToPortIdProperty: "tid"
```

- is setted;

Comment: How do you define the ports in your node template? Example: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/logicCircuit.html

Comment: can you share implemented code?